# Android Java show Western numerals when locale is set to Arabic instead of Eastern Arabic Numerals

Tags: java, android, locale

In Android, if the user chooses Arabic for their language, I want to set the locale to AR but keep all the numbers in the system as "12345". Currently they show as "١٢٣٤٥".

Below is my function to change the locale:

```java
public void setLocale(String lang)
{
    Locale myLocale;

    if (lang.equals("ar"))
    {
        myLocale = new Locale(lang, "SA");

    }
    else
    {
        myLocale = new Locale("en");
    }

    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);

    Resources res = getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    config.setLocale(myLocale);
    config.setLayoutDirection(myLocale);

    Context context = getActivity();
    context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);

    // Save the chosen language in SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("language", lang);
    editor.apply();

    Intent refresh = new Intent(context, getActivity().getClass());
    refresh.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the string number formats by hand.

Java

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("ar","EG")); //Egipt uses western arabic numbers
nf.format(your_string);
```